# How many systemic reactions in inflammation?

Tags: physiology, pathology, inflammation

I have this sentence in my notes

> Inflammation consists of two local reactions and one systemic reactions.

which is difficult for me to accept.
Two local reactions are vascular and cellular.
I think there are two systemic reactions too:

- White blood cell response
- Acute-phase response

**How many systemic reactions there are in the inflammation?**

Answer (score 1):

There are two systemic reactions in inflammation too: mediated by leucocytes and acute-phase response (proteins).